# What is the meaning of the Variant Q-learning and To what INPUT and OUTPUT refer? in Abstract of DeepMind DQN paper 2013

Tags: reinforcement-learning, q-learning, dqn, deep-learning

**-INPUT and OUTPUT OF ATARI DQN:**

In the abstract paragraph of the [DQN](https://www.cs.toronto.edu/%7Evmnih/docs/dqn.pdf) work by DeepMind it has written:

" We present the first deep learning model to **successfully learn control policies** directly from high-dimensional sensory input using reinforcement learning. The model is a convolutional neural network, trained with **a variant of Q-learning**, **whose input is raw pixels and whose output is a value function estimating future rewards**. "

Would you please explain the bold sections?

•   **Input and output refer to Q-learning or DNN?**

•   Why it is said that **learn control policy**, however DQN is composed of QL which is a **value iteration** and"off-policy" algorithm and it is not a **policy iteration** and "on-policy"?

•   What is the meaning of **variant type of Q-learning** is vague? it is **variant** because **approximation** of Q-learning is implemented?